# Search for Facebook Live Videos via Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

Is it possible to search for Facebook Live Videos through the Graph API?
The Facebook Live Video API is all about publishing video, which is not what I want. I have looked through the search API and there does not seem to be any obvious way to search for videos through it.

What I would really like to do is find a list of live videos in a given area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Not at this time.

You can get videos for individual users if they authorize your app, but that's it.

Comment: So how would you request access to an individual's videos?

Comment: @zorro2b GET /me/live_videos

Comment: when I request /me/live_videos with user_videos permission using graphi api explorer I get "(#100) No permission to perform current operation."

Comment: @zorro2b I think you need `publish_actions` as well, but I'm not positive of that.

Comment: Make sure, you use a user access token. Not a page or app access token. We were successful with a user access token to request videos from a page. Not from a user, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used the Graph API via javascript SDK to view my `live_videos` using a user token with scope: `email, public_profile` provided they were created with a privacy setting to `PUBLIC` (using FMLE).  If I create a stream with Wirecast, it starts as `ONLY_ME` and is not accessible via the API.  HTH